# File System Listener

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to have a listener in my application for notifying events when a file is added to the file system. Can someone kindly guide me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link... [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/meteoroid/javax/microedition/io/file/FileSystemRegistry.java.htm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use a [`FileObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to monitor for changes to files or directories.

There seems to be an example [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/os/FileObserver.java.shtml), but I've not tried it so can't vouch for it's correctness.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
new FileObserver(path) {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        if (event == FileObserver.CREATE)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.startWatching();
```