# Is there any listener for delete action from phone storage?

Tags: android, delete-file

I want to know if there is any listener or method to know someone deleting any file from phone storage. When I delete anything I want to create a backup of those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File System Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926280/file-system-listener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found code from [File System Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926280/file-system-listener)

```
new FileObserver(Your_path) {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        if (event == FileObserver.DELETE)
          // File is deleted ,Do what you want
        }
    }.startWatching();
```